# A possible ${\sf (ZF)}$-theorem in the spirit of the $3$-set-lemma

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice, infinite-combinatorics

The number $3$ plays an interesting role in the following statement:

> $\newcommand{\S}{\sf(S_3)}\S$ Let $X$ be a non-empty set and let $f:X \to X$ be fixpoint-free (that is $f(x) \neq x$ for all $x\in X$). Then there are subsets $X_1, X_2, X_3 \subseteq X$ with $X_1\cup X_2\cup X_3 = X$ and $$X_i \cap f(X_i) = \emptyset$$ for $i \in \{1,2,3\}$.

There are easy examples showing that one cannot get by using $2$ subsets only. Statement $\S$ can be [proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3633820/169699) using the axiom of choice. (Although the full force of (AC) is not needed as the strictly weaker [Boolean Prime Ideal Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_prime_ideal_theorem) (BPI) [is sufficient](https://mathoverflow.net/a/358030/8628), but it appears that the $\S$ is not a theorem of $\newcommand{\ZF}{{\sf (ZF)}}\ZF$.)

The motivation of this question is to create a theorem of $\ZF$ in the spirit of $\S$.

**Question.** Is the following statement a theorem of $\ZF$?

> There is a cardinal $\kappa_0 \geq 3$ with the following property: If $X$ is a set with more than $1$ element and $f:X\to X$ is fixpoint-free, then there is a ${\frak S}\subseteq {\cal P}(X)$ with $\bigcup{\frak S} = X$, an injection $\iota:{\frak S}\to \kappa_0$, and the property that $S\cap f(S) = \emptyset$ for all $S\in {\frak S}$.

If the above statement is not a theorem of $\ZF$, then I am wondering about the following special case in $\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}\N$:

> If $f:\N\to\N$ is fixpoint-free, then there is a *finite set* ${\frak S}\subseteq {\cal P}(\N)$ with $\bigcup{\frak S} = \N$ and $S\cap f(S) = \emptyset$ for all $S\in {\frak S}$.

(Note that if we drop the finiteness requirement on ${\frak S}$, then ${\frak S} = \big\{\{n\}:n\in\mathbb{N}\big\}$ is a trivial solution.)

Comment: Your question has $\mathbb N$ where $(S_3)$ has an arbitrary nonempty $X$. Doesn't that change make AC unnecessary in the proof?

Comment: Thanks @AndreasBlass for your comment; I made the question more general in the spirit of ${\sf S}_3$.

Comment: @bof Thanks for your argument for the special case - it's nice to think about it in coloring terms! If you want to elaborate this in an answer, that would be great.

Comment: If $\kappa_0$ is meant to be a well-ordered cardinal, then the statement is equivalent to the axiom of choice for families of finite sets, just like (S$_3$). This is shown in my answer to the linked MO question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "special case in $\mathbb N$" is a theorem of ZF:

**Theorem (ZF).** For any well-orderable set $X$ and any fixpoint-free function $f:X\to X$ there is a family $\mathfrak S\subseteq\mathcal P(X)$ such that $|\mathfrak S|\le3$ and $\bigcup\mathfrak S=X$ and $S\cap f(S)=\varnothing$ for all $S\in\mathfrak S$.

**Proof.** I will show that the graph $G=(X,E)$ with vertex set $X$ and edge set $E=\{\{x,f(x)\}:x\in X\}$ is $3$-colorable. Let $\{C_i:i\in I\}$ be the set of all connected components of $G$. (Of course each $C_i$ is $3$-colorable, being a unicyclic connected graph.) Fix a well-ordering of $X$.

If $C_i$ contains no odd cycle, let $x_i$ be the least vertex in $C_i$. There is a unique proper red-blue vertex coloring of $C_i$ such that $x_i$ is red.

If $C_i$ contains a (necessarily unique) odd cycle, Let $x_i$ be the least vertex in $C_i$ which is not a cut vertex. Then there is a unique proper red-blue-green coloring of $C_i$ such that $x_i$ is the only green vertex and $f(x_i)$ is red.

I don't know about your general statement, but it may be worth mentioning that it's not provable in ZF if we strengthen it by requiring the cardinal $\kappa_0$ to be an aleph:

**Theorem. (ZF)** Suppose that for any set $X$ and any fixpoint-free involution $f:X\to X$ there is a well-orderable family $\mathfrak S\subseteq\mathcal P(X)$ such that $\bigcup\mathfrak S=X$ and $S\cap f(S)=\varnothing$ for all $S\in\mathfrak S$. Then every collection of $2$-element sets has a choice function.

**Proof.** We may assume that the $2$-element sets are disjoint, and then they are the orbits of an involution.

Comment: The statement with a well-orderable family $\mathfrak S$ is equivalent to the axiom of choice for families of finite sets, just like (S$_3$). This is shown in my answer to the MO question linked from the OP.